# AWS API Gateway for Video Stream Fail... Need suggestions for re-implementation of design

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I had plans to use the AWS API Gateway for three purposes. All of these endpoints are configured with custom domain names, with AWS issued SSL certificates and I have CNAME records configure to match the could front urls.

1. api.my-domain.com (REST api calls that return json data) (Working as expected)
2. images.my-domain.com (Proxy pass through of binary image data from S3) - Working as expected.
3. videos.my-domain.com (DOH!... )

Unfortunately dealing with videos I've run into a few issues. Smaller videos start to work but then generate an error. But.. that's not the main issue.

There is a 10MB max payload size on the response data from an API integration endpoint, so I must come up with another solution for the videos.

I don't want to host the images, or videos via cloundfront. And I want to use the same AWS issues wildcard certificate *.my-domain.com on all the endpoints. I wanted to use the API gateway for the image request because the images are small, and won't exceed the limit, and I can cache them at the api level.

a CNAME pointed to my video S3 bucket works, but can't use the same SSL certificate, and I wanted all traffic to originate vie the API gateway and not have request going directly to the bucket endpoint.

```

So.. what are my options?

It seems like my best option will be to transcode the MP4 videos to HLS, and host the S3 bucket via cloudfront. I hadn't really wanted to incur the charges of using cloudfont, but I don't see any better option, for the design I want.

The most recent videos will be viewed occasionally, not high demand, older videos will be viewed rarely so hosting them in cloudfront seems like a waste.

Comment: Looks like I will be trying Vimeo Pro for this...

Comment: CloudFront + S3 is not usually more expensive than S3 alone.  For large objects, it usually costs slightly *less* because CloudFront has better bandwidth pricing, and S3 bandwidth is free when using CloudFront.

Comment: Oh! Thats good to know, I didnt know about free S3 bandwidth! Does it move video to edge locations before its requested, or only when its requested, if video is HLS encoded?

Comment: Content is only fetched by an edge when it is requested through that edge.  Don't take my word for it on the price -- you can verify this on the S3 and CloudFront pricing tables.

Answer (score 0):

Typical setup for Video streaming in AWS is to Stream the Video stored in S3 through AWS [CloudFront RTMP Distribution](http://coverall1.splunk.com/web_assets/developers/httpec/1_awsdiagram.png).

Comment: Yes, thanks... As mentioned I don"t really need or want cloudfront distribution for this use case. The videos will need to be available, but rarely accessed

Answer (score 0):

Going forward with CloudFront hosted content from my S3 bucket to see how it works.

The reason I picked CloudFront overall was the tight integration with other AWS services, and the ability to have complete control over the path/name of the assets in the S3 bucket, whereas with Vimeo you don't have very good control over the name of the assets.